# How to delete row from DataGrid with Delete key

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` and in it some records. What I want is, when I press Delete key on keyboard, the row gets deleted and even the record in collection is deleted.

I thought that the parameter CanUserDeleteRows would do the trick, but it doesn't work. When I press delete, the row disapears, but still remains in the collection.

This is my `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid 
   Name="ProjectsGrid" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FilesCollection}" 
   AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
   CanUserAddRows="False"  
   CanUserDeleteRows="True">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Use" Binding="{Binding Include}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path, Converter={StaticResource PathConverter}}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
namespace Validator.ViewModels
{
  class SettingsVm : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public void ChangeProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<CsprojFile> FilesCollection { get; set;} 
    public SettingsVM()
    {
        FilesCollection = new ObservableCollection<CsprojFile>();
   }
}
```

Do I have to add some event to my ViewModel? Or is there some other way I'm not aware of?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have/use some implementation of [`ICommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand(v=vs.110).aspx) interface? Some `RelayCommand` perhaps?

Comment: Yes I have my own implementation. What do you propose? Should I upload my implementation here for you to see?

Comment: No need. I just wonder why item would stay in your collection. It should be removed, as it does in my case. If your collection would not allow deletion `CanUserDeleteRows` option would be ignored. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canuserdeleterows(v=vs.110).aspx): _**Deleting a row removes the item that the row represents from the ItemsSource**. If the ItemsSource does not allow deletions, the user cannot delete rows even if this property is set to true_

Answer (score 0):

If you want your collection to be updated from View then you should mention binding mode for ItemSource as :

```
<DataGrid 
   Name="ProjectsGrid" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FilesCollection, Mode=TwoWay}" 
   AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
   CanUserAddRows="False"  
   CanUserDeleteRows="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Use" Binding="{Binding Include}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

This should solve your issue

Comment: It should work without two way just as well. You're not changing whole collection but removing an item. In fact item disappearing from view would suggest that it should work as is.